# Have a GitHub Action run when a PR is merged

Tags: github, github-actions

I am looking for a way to have a **GitHub Action run when a PR is merged**, the GitHub Action has to grab the PR description and store the data somewhere for later use.

Is there any way to do this through GitHub Actions without an API or webhook?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two approaches: Either run the workflow when a PR is closed with merge=true or run a workflow on the target branch if you know all pushes to the target branch go through a PR.

---

### Run on PR Closed

You can trigger an action when a PR is closed like so:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
```

The above event is triggered whether a PR was merged or closed without merging. Therefore, you still need to check that flag when running a job:

```yaml
my_job:
  build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
```

---

### Run on Target Branch

If you know all your PRs are merged into `main` and users cannot directly push to `main`, you might as well trigger your workflow on `push` events on main like so:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the great answer.

Only PR get merged into the branch, and a second question, is there any way to store the PR Description for future use somewhere?

Comment: You can dump the entire github context (`github.event.pull_request`) and I'm pretty sure you'll find the description in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this will come in handy to setup the move over to github ^^

Comment: Just sharing my experience after trying this. As of March 20, 2023, using 'true' comparison no longer works. Remove the single quote for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is great but slightly outdated, using `'true'` did not work for me.

The following did the trick for me:

```yaml
jobs:
  publish:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
```

Docs on this: [`jobs.<job_id>.if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif)